Can the four free GRE subject scores be stopped if the score is bad?
When you take the GRE math subject test, we get the option to send our scores to four universities for free.
After I see my score, and if the results aren't good, can I ask ETS to not send the scores? This seems like it would be better than sending bad scores since most universities have it as an optional requirement.

The 4 "free" score reports cannot be cancelled. So if you are really worried about this, you should not request any free score reports; instead, wait until you have a score you like and then order additional score reports (ASRs) to send that score to your prospective programs. However, ASRs cost $35 each, so this is an expensive precaution. Also, subject tests are only offered twice in the Fall (they are offered daily during two two-week intervals, but you may test only once during each interval), so you will likely have very few opportunities to retest, unless you are willing to wait an entire year.

Such a lame racket lol

OTOH, I was surprised to see that there are only 3 subject tests left. Seems like they are on the way out.

@cag51 ETS has also made a number of other big cuts: https://www.insidehighered.com/news/admissions/graduate/2024/06/18/massive-downsizing-ets-legacy-assessment-company
